# Vanity Light Install

Tags: lighting, receptacle, light-fixture, grounding, mirror

I bought an led mirror for our bathroom and can’t figure out how to connect it. The mirror has only a black and white wire while the wiring from the wall has 2 white wires, 2 black wires and 2 green wires. One set of wires goes to an outlet in the bathroom. Any help on how do I connect this mirror? Thanks!

Comment: What was there before and how was it hooked up?

Comment: A vanity light was there before, the electrical outlet was recently added and wired so it went on when the vanity light went on

Answer (score 2):

Connect all three black wires together and all three white wires together with wire nuts. The ground wires will remain connected and should be connected to the junction box if it's metal. If the vanity doesn't have a ground wire,it might get grounded by the mounting bracket.